# What's the easiest way to factor this cubic term?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

A while ago a student has contacted me to explain some exercises in factoring to him. I have since lost contact but one of the exercises I still have and I cannot figure out how you are supposed to do it without looking for zeroes.

$$a^3 + 6a^2b + 11ab^2 + 6b^3$$

$11$ being $5 + 6$ seems kind of suspicious but splitting up the terms in the middle to pull out any of the three linear factors via grouping feels too complicated to me. Is there an easier way?

By the way, the solution is
\begin{align} a^3 + 6a^2b + 11ab^2 + 6b^3 = (a + b)(a + 2b)(a + 3b) \end{align}

Comment: Everything is degree $3$ and the coefficients of odd and even powers of $a$  add up to the same thing $1+11=6+6$ so $a+b$ must be a factor.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, the polynomial is homogeneous, so it's enough to look at $\,x^3-6x^2+11x+6\,$ where $x=a/b$, which "happens" to have all roots rationaL.

Comment: Thanks! I thought maybe there was something simple I was missing. I hadn't heard of these properties before, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Questions should not contain spoilers.

Comment: @Peter - why not?  It shows the questioner knows the answer and is only asking for a good method (i.e. this is not a problem-statement question) while not making it instantly obvious to the casual reader what that answer is.

Comment: @Henry In answers , spoilers make some sense since the author can first try to apply the hint and then check whether he/she got the correct result. But in a question ? If the author knows the result, he/she should just present it (as context).

Comment: @Agiltohr dixv’s trick is quite simple (and useful!). Just factor out $b^3$, and you’ll see you have an expression involving only $\frac ab=:x$ left.

Comment: @Milten Yes, definitely! I should have added that the student was in ~9th grade and they hadn't discussed polynomials yet, they were just practicing factoring. So given that I thought there maybe was some kind of trick I was missing that didn't use any knowledge of polynomials.

Comment: @Peter My thought was that immediately knowing the factors would maybe give answers that unintentionally use them to come up with steps that one would otherwise not. Basically just to approach the problem cleanly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To combine the first two comments:*

The polynomial is homogeneous in degree $3$ so if $x=a/b$ then you are trying to factor $$b^3(x^3+6x^2+11x+6)$$

For the bracketed expression, you might either

- spot that the odd and even coefficients sum to the same value with $1+11=6+6$ so $(x+1)$ is a factor, i.e. $(a+b)$ is a factor of the original expression, or
- hope there are rational factors, which by the rational root theorem would have to be of the form $(x\pm1),(x\pm2),(x\pm3),(x\pm6)$, and testing in this case shows three of these work